# javascript function not defined when hit back button

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have the following example files:

index.html

```
<body>
  <input type="file" name="image" onchange="handleUpload()">
  <script>
    function handleUpload() {
      window.location = 'aa.html';
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

aa.html

```
<body>
  success
</body>
```

After file upload I'm redirected to another page.
When I hit browser back button I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleUpload is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onchange`.

Can someone explain why is this happening? I understand why handleUpload is triggered but why it's undefined?

**Update**

My app is more complex. I use webpack to bundle my js files into a single file then I reference it in layout before closing `body` tag.
What i'm trying to do is a image preview when input file is filled. Everything works great but if I hit back button after the form was submitted I get that error.

I manage to avoid this problem by removing `onchange` from html and added a event listener in one of js file. This approach has a delay on opening the select file window.

Comment: Did you referenced your JS file in the second page?

Comment: It's not a js file (but I tried that too) it is an inline script. I tried putting the script in the second page but doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: i checked it locally in chrome, no problem exists. What browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95 (64-bit). I think it's a browser problem. It doesn't happen in Firefox.

Comment: i have the same version (but 32 bit), are you sure you test these two files correctly?

Comment: yes. chrome triggers `onchange` when hit back button. this doesn't happen in firefox. I'm using mentioned Chrome version on mac.

Comment: what if you move the script before the html input tag? may be the `onchange` is triggered before loading that script function

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Answer

```html
    <input type="file" name="image" onchange="window.location='aa.html'">
```

Comment: My app is more complex. I use webpack to bundle all my js and automatically inject js files before `</body>` tag. `onchange` handler is more complex and redirecting is made by a router. This is a simple example to illustrate the problem.